# Why do some keys in NSUserDefaults have quote marks while others do not?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

When I log my app’s [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/) by passing the results of this code to NSLog:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]]
```

…I get results such as seen in this excerpt.

```
WebKitXSSAuditorEnabled = 1;
WebKitZoomsTextOnly = 1;
"chinese_character_set" = traditional;
"com.testflightapp.had-first-session" = 1;
```

When I add a key (an NSString) and value to NSUserDefaults, my keys have quote marks (QUOTATION MARK, ") surrounding the keys. Yet Apple's entries do not.

Why the difference?

Comment: Your keys have punctuation in their value. That is why they are quoted. This is standard `NSDictionary` output.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. Make that comment an answer so I can accept it.